# How to re-activate the GUI of a app?

Tags: gui

I have ticked the option minimize to system tray for the app minbar. Now I can't run the GUI interface of the program. When I click the Icon, the program runs cause I can use the pidof command and see the process ID. But I can't bring up the GUI of the App. How do I bring that back?

Comment: thanks, it helped so much !! whenever i click on "start minimized" this bug always happen, and this answer always solves it. now i have to find how to actually be able to start it hidden, and also find the app indicator, just like i can do in my mint17 without any problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the [gconftool-2 - GNOME configuration tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gconftool-2.1.html) to change the **starthidden** value from *true* to ***false***.

**1)** Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `gconftool-2 --set /apps/minbar/prefs/starthidden --type=bool false`

**2)** Finally open the **minbar** application and the **Gui** should be activated.

Hope this helps.